# Text size won't stick in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I want the default text size in IE 9 to be "Smaller" (View -> Text Size). However, whenever I restart the browser, the size goes back to "Medium". I looked through the settings, but I don't see where I can change this. Is there a way to make my text size choice be the default so that I don't have to keep changing the text size after every browser session?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. In Internet Options | Advanced, there is an option for "Reset text size to medium for new windows and tabs".